# regex cannot find the expected string

Tags: java, regex

HI I am trying to match the following string in java:

```
echo "a"b
```

with this tedious regex:

```
String SPACE_REGEX = "[^\\s]+|\\s\"([^\"]*)\"|\\s\"([^\"]*)\"[^\\s]+";
```

The problem is in the second `matcher.find()`, the matcher is able to match the `group(1)` to `"a"`, but the `group(2)` cannot find the string `"a"b`

Below is the testing code:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(SPACE_REGEX);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(str);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
     System.out.println(regexMatcher.group(1) + " " + regexMatcher.group(2));
}
```

And here is the output:

```
null null 
a null
null null
```

Can someone please have a look on this regex? I have tried the group 2 regex on OnlineRegexTest and it does work, but I dont understand why it is does not work here in java.

**UPDATE**

What I am trying to is matching the quoted string `"a"` in such command

```
echo "a" b or echo "a"
```

but not in

```
echo b"a"b or echo "a"b
```

I will do a check with the matcher result like

```
if (matcher.group(1) != null && matcher.group(2) == null) 
    print("found")
```

Comment: The third alternative will never be matched, because the second alternative will match first.

Comment: FYI, `[^\\s]` can be simplified to just `\\S`

Comment: When you have alternatives in the regexp, only one of them matches at a time. So you can't get both `group(1)` and `group(2)` in the same match.

Comment: Why do you expect to find `" a"b`? That doesn't appear in the input.

Comment: @anubhava Sorry for not making it clear at the first time, already updated it now.

Comment: @Barmar it should be `"a"b`. And thanks for the clarification about the property! Could you please have a look on my update and give some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String SPACE_REGEX = "\\s\"([^\"]*)\"(?:\\s|$)";
```

This matches a space, then a quoted string, then either a space or the end of the string.

The contents of the string will be in `group(1)`.